# xmppframework (iOS) under 3G network can't work

Tags: ios, openfire, 3g, xmppframework

Im using the xmppframework framework for XMPP. My app works fine under wifi but not under 3G.
Here's how it looks like after I start my app:

```
SEND: <?xml version='1.0'?>
SEND: <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='mydomain'>
```

And then it receives nothing. Sometimes it receives feedback from openfire server after a long time, but for the most time it receives nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem:

```
[xmppStream setHostName:@"123.123.123.123"]; //ADD IP ADDRESS OF YOUR JABBER SERVER
```

This is what i did in my APPDelegate File.

Connected under 3G :)